# How to implement min max facet (similar to stats aggregation in Elasticsearch) in azure search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Our index has price field, and I want to dynamically get the min/max price of all products for a given search phrase. This feature could be implemented with stats aggregation in Elasticsearch, but how to implement it using Azure search facet?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Search does support range facets. What's **not included is min/max values** in responses.

You could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/8382225-add-aggregations-functionality) to promote the feature that `expose functionality equivalent to Elasticsearch aggregations` to be achieved.

Comment: Is your solution same to Liam's solution?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out another option as work around. The idea is to sort the facet by value.

Take price as example:

1. Define two fields for price in index when creating the index

   ```
   "fields": [
       { "name": "price", "type": "Edm.Double", "facetable": true }
       { "name": "price_copy", "type": "Edm.Double", "facetable": true}
   ]
   ```
2. Put same value to both price and price_copy field when upload the documents

```
  "value": [  
    {  
      "@search.action": "upload",  
      "price": 19.99,
      "price_copy": 19.99
    }]
```

3. Send facet request

```
    facet=price,sort:value,count:1&facet=price_copy,sort:-value,count:1
```

The response will be something like this:

```
"@search.facets": {
    "price": [
        {
            "count": 45,
            "value": 0
        }
    ],
    "price_copy": [
        {
            "count": 20,
            "value": 2899.99
        }
    ]
}
```

Then we can pick up the min/max value of the price from price and price_copy facet respectively. I think this solution is better, as it could get the more accurate min/max value compared with the bucket range workaround as Liam suggested.

Any thought?

Comment: How would that actually work in practice? Doesn't a single document only have a single price? Or are there multiple prices per document?

Comment: Thanks your comment. Yes, my idea is to define two fields for price and set same value to two price fields per each document. I just updated my answer to be more understandable.

Comment: That seems to work. The most obvious cost is the added storage for adding another facetable field. Also, be aware that if your Edm.Double fields contain NaNs, they may sort in ways you don't expect.

Comment: Thanks. A another work around is, we can send extra two request to azure search, each of which sort by the price value on asc and desc respectively, then we can get min/max price from above two response. The cost is, we need send extra http requests. If we have, say, 5 facets need min/max, we need send 10 more requests. What do you think about this approach compared to the duplicate field approach?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to optimize for -- storage usage, or latency. Either way, it's something you ought to be able to measure. If you're optimizing for latency, I'd say the approach where you can get the min and max in a single request should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Fully agree with Joel as the correct answer, however another option would be to facet over the price and get all the potential prices and then on client side take the min and max.  Obviously that would not be nearly as performant as Joel's option and might be unrealistic if you have a significant number of different prices.  In that case, I think you could do bucket ranges of prices (for example count of $0-$10, $10-20, etc...) to find the max and min bucket price range which would decrease the number of facets that would come back.